# How to make a window not open when the app loads XCode

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nswindow

If I have a NSWindow in Interface Builder and run my app, it opens.

How do I prevent this from happening? I'd like this window to only be opened when the user presses a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IB , you can find a check box named "Visible at Launch" in attributes tab.
You can uncheck that.So that window will not launch on app loading time

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) For some reason my Interface Builder was not focusing on the window but instead on the view inside it.